# Compile C code in Visual Studio in Windows for Linux

Tags: c, linux, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm using Visual Studio in Windows to develop basic C applications. I want to compile my code for Linux, without the need to have Linux installed on my machine. Is that possible ? And how ?

Comment: You can't _compile_ from Visual Studio, but you could use it as a text editor. But then I don't really see the need to compile it in Windows itself. Back in the days, one used a telnet connection to some remote Solaris and then compiled it on the actual target system, with full access to the Unix shell. Too easy I guess...

Comment: @Lundin, I agree. However, maybe Youssef does not have a machine with a Linux based os and he does not want to install it on his current machine (partitioning the mem et cetera). So in this context, the question makes sense. The real question is another one: why do you want to compile for linux when you do not have a machine with linux?

Comment: @Leos313 I'm sure there's some Linux "sandbox" somewhere on the internet that lets you play around on it.

Comment: @Leos313, to send it for people who have Linux :)

Comment: oh, then you can test it on your machine but they MUST compile the code in their machine!! the compiled code not always can be sent to be run on other machines!! be careful

Comment: Why it must be compiled in their machine ? Most software available are already compiled for different platforms, and you usually download the one that is suitable for your platform. This is exactly what I want. Currently, if I send my exe to another Windows machine, it works correctly. I want to have another compiled file that can be sent to Linux machines and work correctly too.

Comment: @Youssef13 for example, if the processors are different: if you use a x86 and the program need to run on an embedded system with an arm processor, you will face the problem. Or, more simply, if you have a 64 bit processor and the other machine are 32 bit et cetera et cetera

Comment: however, when you face a problem like that, **cross-compiling** is the solution

Comment: @Leos313, Shouldn't 32bit apps work on both, 32bit and 64 machines ? And anyways, how can I compile the program for different machines from my Windows machine ? How can I do cross-compiling ?

Comment: @Youssef13, ask other questions on StackOverflow. However, with the keyword "cross-compiling" you will find A LOT A LOT of stuff on the web! Enjoy! :)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler

Comment: @Leos313, I need an answer that is specific to my environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to have Linux installed somewhere. If you can remote to a linux box, vm, or WSL console, from your Visual Studio machine, you can use VS 2019 to build and debug most applications in any of those environments, via the [Cross Platform Connection Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/linux/connect-to-your-remote-linux-computer?view=vs-2019).

The following blog and document links are a good place to start.

- [Targeting the Windows Subsystem for Linux from Visual Studio](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/targeting-windows-subsystem-for-linux-from-visual-studio/)
- [C++ with Visual Studio 2019 and Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c-with-visual-studio-2019-and-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl/)
- [EA and Visual Studio’s Linux Support](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/ea-and-visual-studios-linux-support/)
- [Usability Improvements for CMake in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.4: Launch Target Selection and Overview Pages](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/usability-improvements-for-cmake-in-visual-studio-2019-version-16-4-launch-target-selection-and-overview-pages/)

Similarly, Visual Studio Code has some support for this as well:

- [Using C++ and WSL in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-wsl)

Sincerely,

Answer (score 1):

yes, it is possible.
Have a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051525/windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl-what-cant-i-do-with-the-ubuntu-application-f) stackoverflow question.

1. Install WLS on your Windows machine
2. Use the standard `gcc` instruction (or, better, `Makefiles` and/or `CMake`)

**Example**:

Let's say you have your program:

```
//code within filename.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("Hello Youssef\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Then, within the folder, run:

```
$ gcc filename.c
```

and then run it:

```
$ ./a.out
Hello Youssef
```

Comment: Will that be compatible with some functions that, ASFAIK, are MSVC-specific ?

Comment: @Youssef13, the answer in the last comment following the question: you cannot send the compiled code. Normally it does not work. Instead, test on your machine and send them the script to compile and run the code in thei machine

Answer (score 0):

You can install a VM (virtual machine) on your windows computer, then install linux on the virtual machine.

Note: both the VM and linux are free downloads

Comment: Does that mean there is no way to do this directly on Windows ?